# Why doesn't watch bash -c '"echo $RANDOM"' print anything?

Tags: bash, variable, watch

I expect this command to print a random value to the screen every 2 seconds, but instead it doesn't print anything:

```
watch bash -c '"echo $RANDOM"'
```

This command, however, does print a random value every 2 seconds:

```
watch bash -c '"echo \$RANDOM"'
```

Apparently I have to escape the dollar sign, but I'd like to understand why, because in the first case the watch command reports at the top to be executing the commandd correctly:

```
Every 2.0s: bash -c "echo $RANDOM"
```

In the second case it reports to be executing this command, as expected:

```
Every 2.0s: bash -c "echo \$RANDOM"
```

Ok I get it, the dollar sign has to be escaped to reach the bash command properly. But still, Why? What does the watch command do to $RANDOM before executing the command to make it not output anything?

Comment: Not reproducible on my system. CentOS 7.9 displays random numbers every two seconds using your first command.

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu with WSL in Windows.

Comment: @doneal24, CentOS has Bash as `sh`, so the intermediate shell that `watch` starts expands`$RANDOM`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like @steeldriver mentioned in a comment, by default `watch` runs the command through `sh -c`. It appears to join any arguments it gets with spaces first, though.

With

```
watch bash -c '"echo $RANDOM"'
```

it gets the args `bash`, `-c`, `"echo $RANDOM"`, produces `bash -c "echo $RANDOM"`, and runs `sh` with the two args `-c` and `bash -c "echo $RANDOM"`.

Then `sh` a variable within double quotes and duly expands it. If your `sh` doesn't support the special `$RANDOM`, the whole variable is probably not set, and you get an empty string there. Then the resulting command is `bash -c "echo "`, which starts Bash, telling it to print just a newline.

(If your `sh` is Bash and does have `$RANDOM`, then you could have just used `watch 'echo $RANDOM'`.)

If you add the backslash, the outer shell (`sh`) there sees `... "echo \$RANDOM"`, which doesn't expand, but just removes the backslash. The inner shell (`bash`) sees `echo $RANDOM` and expands the variable itself. Same if you arrange the outer shell to get `... 'echo $RANDOM'`, with single quotes.

You can see the expansion the intermediate shell makes with something like this (it should print `out`):

```
export foo=out; watch 'bash -c "foo=in; echo $foo"'
```

With `watch -x`, it'd skip the intervening shell, and this would work in the way you expect without the quoting hell:

```
watch -x bash -c 'echo $RANDOM'
```

Comment: Who is @steeldriver? I don't see him anywhere, but you start your answer with "Like @steeldriver mentioned in a comment..."

Comment: @Adrian, [a user on the site](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/65304/steeldriver), not that you can search by username (I think), and I guess they deleted their comment since I can't see it any more.

Answer (score 1):

From the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/watch):

> Note that command is given to "sh -c" ...

If you execute `echo $RANDOM` using `sh` instead of `bash` you will get no output because `$RANDOM` is available in `bash`, but not in `sh`.

Comment: Fun fact: According to the linked man page: "You can watch for your administrator to install the latest kernel with watch uname -r"

Comment: it says "Just kidding" right below that. You will never see a new version with that, as changing the kernel requires a reboot.

Comment: @Panki I know. The fun fact I wanted to point out is not that you can do that, but the fact that the author said something like that.